# Renaming files in Windows using FOR

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, batch-rename

The task is to rename five random files to renamed1.ren, renamed2.ren, ..., renamed5.ren using the command line. Here is what I've come to:

```
set i=1
for /f "tokens=*" %f in ('dir /b') do (
ren %f renamed%i%.ren
set /a i+=1)
```

I expected `i` to be incremented in every iteration, but that didn't work. What can I change?

Comment: Do you really want to change the extension of the files ? ! That seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one liner that does not require delayed expansion.

From the command line:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %A in ('dir /b^|findstr /n "^"') do @ren "%B" "renamed%A.ren"
```

Within a batch script

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('dir /b^|findstr /n "^"') do ren "%%B" "renamed%%A.ren"
```

Comment: Wow, this one worked just fine, thanks. Could you please explain a little bit of this magic? This one in particular: `'dir /b^|findstr /n "^"'`.

Comment: @dardvas - I pipe the output of your DIR /B to FINDSTR. The regular expression search string of `"^"` matches the beginning of a line, and is guaranteed to match all lines. The `/n` option prefixes each match with the line number, followed by a colon.

Answer (score 2):

```dos
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION    
set i=1
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b') do (
 ren %%f renamed!i!.ren
 set /a i+=1)
```

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Within a batch file, the loop-control variable references require to have the `%` doubled.

Comment: And what if I work in the command line, not in the batch file? Have just tried to run the code you suggested (without doubling %) and it worked the same way.

Comment: Different people work in different ways. If you want to type all that in instead of using a batch file, that's up to you. I'd record it as a batch file, myself.

Comment: By the "same way" I meant that it didn't work properly like in my first case. May be the `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` doesn't work in command line?